# While LOOP - PHP - Close Brackets Dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a Database table

```
Column1 | Column2
-----------------
    1   | Program1 
    2   | Program2
    3   | Program3
```

.
.
.

These are listed as Checkbox in a web page..
Before the User clicks submit I need him to select atleast on program

This is my javascript

```
var chkd = document.form1.Program1.checked
      if (chkd) {
        return true;
      } else {
         var chkd2 = document.form1.Program2.checked
         if (chkd2) {
           return true; 
         } else {
            var chkd3 = document.form1.Program3.checked
            if (chkd3) {
              return true; 
            } else {
                var chkd4 = document.form1.program4.checked
                if (chkd4) {
                  return true;
                } else {
            var chkd5 = document.form1.Program5.checked
                    if (chkd5) {
                    return true;
                  } else {      
                   alert ("Please select atleast one training program");
                   return false; 
                             }
            }
                   }
               }
            }
```

Till now the number of programs were static now the need is to change them dynamically. New programs will be added and old one removed.

Putting the checkboxes from the Database I have made it by loop but I cant get the javascript to be echoed out by loop properly (I cant get to close brackets)

Here is what I did so far,

```
$sql=blah blah blah
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
echo "<script>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    if ($_SESSION["$row[1]"]=="Y") 
        {
        echo "
        var chkd$row[0] = document.form1.$row[1].checked 
        if (chkd$row[0]) {
            return true;
        } else {
        ";
        }
    }
echo "</script>";
?>
```

This output's

```
<script>
var chkd1 = document.form1.Program1.checked 
if (chkd1) {
    return true;
} else {

var chkd2 = document.form1.Program2.checked 
if (chkd2) {
    return true;
} else {

var chkd3 = document.form1.Program3.checked 
if (chkd3) {
    return true;
} else {

var chkd4 = document.form1.Program4.checked 
if (chkd4) {
    return true;
} else {

var chkd6 = document.form1.Program5.checked 
if (chkd6) {
    return true;
} else {
</script>
```

Now how can I dynamically close as many brackets as I have opened in the javascript..
I am an absolute beginner and I am still learning so I cant get the syntax right. 
Apologies for such a long post.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it is `document.form1` and not `document.forms.form1` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're returning you don't need the else at all, Javascript will stop execution of the function when it get's told to return.

```
   var chkd1 = document.form1.Program1.checked 
    if (chkd1) {
        return true;
    }

   var chkd2 = document.form1.Program2.checked 
    if (chkd2) {
        return true;
    }

   var chkd3 = document.form1.Program3.checked 
    if (chkd3) {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Now my bracket problem is solved ;). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could always add a counter, then iterate through that many times closing the brackets.

```
$count=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($_SESSION["$row[1]"]=="Y") 
    {
        echo "
            var chkd$row[0] = document.form1.$row[1].checked 
            if (chkd$row[0]) {
                return true;
            } else {
            ";
        $count++;
    }
}
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
    echo "}";
}
```

Comment: Although mine answers your question, listen to scragar, as his solution is far more reasonable.

Comment: Yes you are right, this way it works but as scragar pointed out there is no need to add 'else' I will simply remove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to output anything by loop. Just do in Javascript:

```
for (var key in document.forms.form1.children) // not just document.form1
    if (document.forms.form1.children[key].name != undefined && document.forms.form1.children[key].name.substring(0,7) == "Program" && document.forms.form1.children[key].checked)
        return true;
alert ("Please select atleast one training program");
return false;
```

Comment: This code is too complicated for me to digest.. But as I can understand little bit this assumes there are 7 programs which wont work in my scenario. Thanks.

Comment: @huz_akh No, the word "Program" consists of 7 characters. I'm checking oall children's names to see if the first 7 characters are "Program".

Answer (score 0):

User has checked or not checked checkbox using [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) you can easily manage. for this you don't have to genrate javascript code dynamically.

just put this code and it will return true if user has checked any one or more than one checkbox and return false is checkbook is not checked.

```
if($("INPUT[checkbox]").is(':checked'))
{
      return true;   
}else {
      return false;
}
```

i hope this will help you..

Comment: You are assuming JQuery is used

Comment: I have no knowledge of jquery.. sorry